# How to stop adding IP from EC2 to known_hosts for ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, amazon-ec2

I start/stop lots of new instances as I'm learning to use Amazon EC2. Every temporary instance is added to the known_hosts file. Is this ever a problem for others who use EC2 a lot?

I'd like to tell ssh to skip this step anytime I connect to amazonaws.com. Is there a way to do that in the config? I'm using Linux & openssh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done to prevent Man in the Middle attacks.  Disabling it would disable basic functionality of the ssh tools.

You may want to keep a copy of your `.ssh/known_hosts` file without the entries and replace it when you are done.

Comment: You can create a simple bash function for these such as `ecssh () { ssh $1; cp .ssh/saved_hosts .ssh/known_hosts }` <-- That syntax isn't exact, but it shows the idea.

Comment: Thanks. I believe for EC2 you're supposed to check the fingerprint with the instance's system log.

Comment: Found the issue with my syntax. Needs a semicolon after the `cp` command: ecssh () { ssh $1; cp .ssh/saved_hosts .ssh/known_hosts; }

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
ssh -q -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $MYKEY $MYUSERNAME@$MYIP $MYCOMMAND
```

You can also do this in your config file:

```
Host *.amazonaws.com
  User root
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  LogLevel QUIET
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script that fixes this.  It uses cloud-init pubkeys logged via the EC2 console output.  (Which you actually noted in your comment is the only correct approach).

Basically, you tell it an instance name, and it finds that instance ID + IP, and makes a custom UserKnownHostsFile for it, using the pubkeys it finds in the console output, and launches SSH with the other arguments passed.

https://github.com/kjpgit/ec2ssh/blob/master/ec2ssh.py